# Is a relative adverb omitted in this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis

Between ***weight*** and ***they***, is a relative adverb omitted?
The sentence structure eludes me.

> Evolution works to maximize the number of descendants that an animal
> leaves behind. Where the risk of death from fishing increases as an
> animal grows, evolution favors those that grow slowly, mature younger
> and smaller, and reproduce earlier. This is exactly what we now see in
> the wild. Cod in Canada’s Gulf of St. Lawrence begin to reproduce at
> around four today; forty years ago they had to wait until six or seven
> to reach maturity. Sole in the North Sea mature **at half the body
> weight they did in 1950**.

[The Ocean of Life: The Fate of Man and the Sea](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=KbG7HxoURbgC&pg=PT29&lpg=PT29&dq=This%20is%20exactly%20what%20we%20now%20see%20in%20the%20wild.%20Cod%20in%20Canada%E2%80%99s%20Gulf%20of%20St.%20Lawrence%20begin%20to%20reproduce%20at%20around%20four%20today;%20forty%20years%20ago%20they%20had%20to%20wait%20until%20six%20or%20seven%20to%20reach%20maturity.%20Sole%20in%20the%20North%20Sea%20mature%20at%20half%20the%20body%20weight%20they%20did%20in%201950.&source=bl&ots=D9uNOnQKS9&sig=ACfU3U2swE2FxoJaX9EtcUjDV_9UCeM2gw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihw4nCsf7sAhVFeXAKHfsGBSAQ6AEwBnoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=This%20is%20exactly%20what%20we%20now%20see%20in%20the%20wild.%20Cod%20in%20Canada%E2%80%99s%20Gulf%20of%20St.%20Lawrence%20begin%20to%20reproduce%20at%20around%20four%20today%3B%20forty%20years%20ago%20they%20had%20to%20wait%20until%20six%20or%20seven%20to%20reach%20maturity.%20Sole%20in%20the%20North%20Sea%20mature%20at%20half%20the%20body%20weight%20they%20did%20in%201950.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

You could put a subordinator "that" in there.

> Sole in the North Sea mature at half the body weight **that** they did in 1950.

The omission of "that" is allowed, and the sentence reads better without it.

Comment: +1 for adding **that**, but I disagree that the sentence reads better without it. In my opinion, **that** can be omitted in spoken English, but it's just laziness to omit it in written English.